# How to get the activity running from other process using Robotium

Tags: android, android-activity, automated-tests, robotium

i have a main activity and when tap on the button in the main activity it moves to the another activity than runs on another process .. is there a chance to track/get that activity using robotium /by means of other codes to integrate with robotium

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no. Robotium builds upon Android's instrumentation objects which are limited to work only within the process of the instrumentation for the given target Activity (as you define a target process in the test-manifest file).

I don't know how it behaves in cases where the target process has a defined shared user id, though...